# Merging multiple satellite bands for science data set rasters?

Tags: arcgis-pro, remote-sensing, modis, multi-band

I am using MODIS satellite imagery data for one specific derived band. The problem I am running into is that it is a MCD19 SDS layer, which contains different bands for each orbit overpass at a specific location (up to 15 times). Because of this, I was wondering if it was possible to merge multiple bands together into one band to display in stretch symbology and average any overlapping imagery. I am currently using ArcGIS Pro but not able to find any geoprocessing or raster tools that fit this criteria for the TIFF images I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try using raster calculator to calculate a single summarizing statistic based on all 15 bands.

You will have to have each band separated as a one-band raster dataset or as a raster layer in the map.

I have never used this this, but the Band Collection Statistics tools sounds useful.